# Create raw unicode character from hex string representation

Tags: string, unicode, julia

Given the string hex representation of a Unicode character, I would like to print the Unicode character it represents

```
julia> s1, s2 = raw"\u0041", raw"\x41"
julia> println(s1,' ', s2)
\u0041 \x41
```

Instead, I want it to print "A A"

Use Case:
For a demo, I would like to loop over a range of values and print a map from the hex representation to the Unicode:

```
for ii = 0x0021 : 0x007f
    hex_rep = string(ii, base=16)
    unicode = raw"\u" * lpad(hex_rep, 4, '0')
    println(hex_rep, " -> ", unicode)
end
```

Comment: Possibly https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.unescape_string

Comment: Why are you converting to a string first? Why not go directly from hex to character?

Comment: @DNF Because it has been a while since I used a language that distinguishes strings and chars and my mind was focused on making it work with strings . So Char is the right way for my actual use case while unescape_string is the best approach to my question as asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just do:

```
julia> Char.(0x0021 : 0x007f)
95-element Vector{Char}:
 '!': ASCII/Unicode U+0021 (category Po: Punctuation, other)
 '"': ASCII/Unicode U+0022 (category Po: Punctuation, other)
 '#': ASCII/Unicode U+0023 (category Po: Punctuation, other)
 ⋮
 '}': ASCII/Unicode U+007D (category Pe: Punctuation, close)
 '~': ASCII/Unicode U+007E (category Sm: Symbol, math)
 '\x7f': ASCII/Unicode U+007F (category Cc: Other, control)
```

For other cases consider using the forementioned `unescape_string`